# How to decide which item will be shown at first in the screen in android gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

I have a gallery that consist of small size of pictures and when I click any of them a gallery comes to screen with bigger images of those small pictures. And for example I clicked the 3. picture of gallery, in the second screen I want to see the 3. picture first but when I scroll it left or right I want to see other pictures. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass that selected `int` to next screen and then do this:

```
galleryView.setSelection(3); //3 or whatever you send your position from previous screen
```

Remember do this, after setting the `Adapter` to `Gallery`.